# Adapt a 'buffer hack' .blend for 3.5.0-geometry-nodes-simulation

Tags: geometry-nodes

This question is address to to those who already use [3.5.0-geometry-nodes-simulation](https://builder.blender.org/download/experimental/).
I have made this [.blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Dkj94N28/) based on the [“buffer hack”](https://www.blendernation.com/2022/11/15/simulations-solvers-in-geometry-nodes/) and I would like to know how to adapt it for this experimental version of blender. There is no tutorials I can find about this version so if you have any addresses they are welcome to. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Timaroberts Thanks for the Edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the pong node and use this node setup:

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot Chris, I new it was easy, but I cant figure out...

Comment: that's always that way. If you know it, it is easy. If you don't know - it seems impossible ;)